# Dealing with lots of text input changes in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a small app in Redux, and am wondering to what extend **all** state changes should propagate through Redux reducers & the central store.

For example, is it better for single text inputs to manage their own state within their own component (via `setState`)?  Or, should actions be fired in response to every single keydown event in these inputs.  If so, I'm wondering if there might be a performance problem.

Overall, what's the best practice for handling minor UI updates such as keypress events in Redux?

Comment: just use onBlur event instead of onChange ( this will save almost 99% renders ) for this you need to pass defaultValue instead of value in prop and its always good to maintain the global props,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux is for managing state in a predictable way. State means data, and that applies equally to data from an API or from the client UI.

In a small app, I would start with the vision of *all state redux-ed* until I really actually run into performance issues. This includes visual state, menus, user input.

The redux state tree can be highly optimized, to handle a lot of input and updates through reducers. Largely in part because we're dealing with immutable objects passed by reference.

I've written production apps managing state with Redux that can handle large updates over websockets every 100ms, and have complex menu actions like visual date components, and they've all played together nicely.

To bolster your confidence, here's a [tweet from Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/684074628227182592).

ps. worst case, if you start seeing performance issues with the inputs, you could just debounce the input field.

Answer (score 1):

If the text input values are needed globally in your app, it is better to store them inside the redux store. Else you can store it inside your local state say, rect component state if your app is a react-redux app.

And whether to dispatch an action in each keystroke, that depends on your use case. Let's say you are writing something in a description field. The description can be lengthy and you don't need to dispatch an action for a service call on each keystroke, because it would result in a lot of unnecessary service calls. 
One way to solve this problem is to dispatch an action only when the user pauses between keystrokes. Debounce is a javascript plugin which can be used to cover such scenarios. Using debounce, you can configure the delay for dispatching actions. You can checkout the debounce plugin here : https://github.com/component/debounce.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need these input values outside of input components, you can store them in local state, instead of using redux state.

Global redux state in most cases should contain data, which is used by many components.